# Ubuntu notebook computer lost its GUI

Tags: nvidia, graphics, gnome-shell, 22.04

After trying to switch from Intel driver to the Nvidia graphics driver on my notebook computer, using **Software Updates** option from the `gnome-control-center`, it now boots only to command prompt with no attempt to display a graphical login screen. I tried all the "terminals", using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, and so on, but none has the GUI login prompt.

I tried some answers in AskUbuntu, like reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop`, using the `tasksel` command to (re)install desktop, removing and reinstalling NVIDIA drivers, trying to switch back to Intel driver, using `systemctl set-default graphical.target`, but none of them helped.

I have done similar graphics driver switches (Intel ⟷ Nvidia) in the previous versions of Ubuntu for various reasons and never had this problem. My system was upgraded to 22.04 from 21.10 in the end of April. I am using this very system since 18.10 and upgraded every six months with no Ubuntu re-installation so far. The system is fully updated.

The `startx` command opens a tiny white terminal at the top left corner of the screen. I can run the command `gnome-shell` to bring up GNOME, but it is very slow and some GUI tools like `gnome-terminal` or `gnome-control-center` just crash.

I also noticed that the directory `/etc/X11` and its sub-directories of are all empty now. It may be a problem with `Xorg`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was fixed after purging and reinstalling `gdm3`:

```
$ sudo apt purge gdm3
$ sudo apt install gdm3 ubuntu-desktop
```

After the above, I noticed that a file named `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` appeared and it has the following contents:

```
/usr/sbin/gdm3
```